# Why does a plurality of Israelis hold a favorable view on China?

Tags: china, israel

> Majorities in nine of the 11 European countries surveyed also hold
> unfavorable views of China. Those in Sweden, the Netherlands and
> Germany are particularly negative: About three-quarters or more say
> their opinion of China is unfavorable. Roughly two-thirds in the UK
> and France agree. Views in Greece are more divided, with 50% saying
> they have an unfavorable view and 44% holding a favorable view.
>
> Opinions in Israel are also divided, with roughly equal shares holding
> unfavorable and favorable views (46% vs. 48%).

https://www.pewresearch.org/global/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2022/06/PG_2022.06.29_views-of-china_REPORT.pdf

Why does a plurality of Israelis hold (or held a favorable view before October 7) on China? According to a recent Pew Research poll, it seems that a small plurality of Israelis holds a favorable view of China. Higher than other countries in the democratic West, although Israel may not be exactly considered to be a Western country, although it has strong ties with a lot of Western countries due to its democratic leanings. Is there a particular reason for that?

Comment: That was from before Oct 7. I'm not sure if all those China vetoes/votes at the UN on [not] condemning Hamas etc., didn't move the dial in the meantime.

Comment: Is there any reason that Israelis should a priori have a view one way or the other about China?

Comment: This question (and a couple similar questions) [are being discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6834/what-should-we-do-with-all-those-why-do-country-people-view-country-favorab).

Comment: What is the margin of error on that poll? Once that is factored into the data they might not be the plurality anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some [details from July 2023 poll](https://www.jpost.com/israel-news/article-752744):

> Nearly half (48%) of Israelis feel that China does not take their country into consideration at all, and another 33% say it does not account for Israel's interests much; only 12% said China takes Israel into account a fair amount. Israelis' 81% negative rating of China on this question is worse than the median, which is 76%.
>
> Over three-quarters (77%) of Israelis said China does not contribute to global peace and stability, with 39% saying not at all and 38% saying not too much. Only 16% said that China helps bring peace and stability a fair amount. Israelis' 77% negative rating of China on this question is worse than the median, which is 71%.
>
> Israelis are split as to whether China interferes in other countries' affairs, with 50% saying yes to varying degrees and 42% saying no. The 24-country median of those saying China interferes in other countries is 57%.
>
> Most Israelis (72%) have little or no confidence in Chinese President Xi Jinping, similar to the median of 74% who feel the same.
>
> Fewer Israelis view China as the world's leading economic power this year (20%) than they did in 2019 (27%). A slim majority of Israelis (52%) see China's economic power as neutral, while 39% see it as a bad thing and 6% view it positively.
>
> Most (61%) Israelis say that China's technological achievements are the best or above average, and 55% say the same of China's military. Israelis are far less likely to view Chinese universities (27%) or entertainment (11%) as good.

So, Israelis are/were impressed by China tech apparently, but not much else. There's a more in-depth [article](https://carnegieendowment.org/2021/10/27/how-china-learned-to-harness-israel-s-media-and-booming-tech-scene-pub-85653) on how China chose to make tech cooperation with Israel a pillar of their relations, recently.

It's also worth noting though that there's substantial year-to-year variation in the results on this poll:

> Israelis' view of China has gotten worse in recent years. In 2019, China had its least unfavorable rating in Israel, 25%, which dropped to 46% last year.

TBH, IDK what explains the large swings on this.

Speaking of the 2022 poll though, another newspaper [chose](https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2022-06-29/ty-article/.highlight/israelis-not-concerned-by-chinas-human-rights-record-survey-finds/00000181-af69-dc74-a78f-affba54c0000) to emphasize that Israelis were not particularly concerned with China's human rights record.

> Fifty-seven percent of Israelis said they would support strengthening economic relations with China even if it means not addressing human rights issues – which was behind only South Korea and Singapore. Meanwhile, only 21 percent supported trying to promote human rights in China even if it harms economic relations with Beijing. This was the lowest rate in the world. [...] Israel is the only country to consider economic competition as a top issue over human rights concerns in relations with China. [...]
>
> Within Israel, views on China’s human rights situation were sharply divided on partisan lines: 27 percent of Israelis identifying as leftists saw the issue as very serious, compared to just 5 percent on the Israeli right.

Comment: N.B. In 2020 COVID-19 happened, so maybe that had an effect on China's rapidly dropping popularity in Israel, as it happened in [many] other countries, although in some staunchly pro-China countries like Serbia, Covid-19 had no effect on China's image there https://www.asiamaior.org/the-journal/16-asia-maior-special-issue-2-2022/covid-19-and-chinas-global-image.html

Comment: Somewhat in tandem with the US, Israel stopped granting China new port, desalinization, and rail line contracts, apparently on national security concerns https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/2023-06-28/ty-article/.premium/netanyahus-dangerous-fortune-cookie-diplomacy-with-china-and-the-u-s/00000189-0186-d0cb-a98f-0f979a020000

Comment: I wonder why Covid19 should have a negative impact on China's reputation. My question comes from the completely opposite attitudes of China and the United States towards tracing the origin of the virus, which is analogous to the attitudes of the United States and China towards the investigation of the Nord Stream pipeline incident. Could this be another Spanish Flu?

Comment: I'm confused about what national security here refers to that actually exists. Although you call it "apparently", it doesn't seem to be apparent. Combined with the Iraq War and the Palestinian-Israeli conflict, the national security advocated by the United States and Israel seems quite aggressive.

Comment: ...Speaking of that, it appears that Israel and China are united in a belief that national security trumps human rights, so it's not surprising.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does a plurality of Israelis hold (or held a favorable view before October 7) on China? According to a recent Pew Research poll, it seems that a small plurality of Israelis holds a favorable view of China. Higher than other countries in the democratic West, although Israel may not be exactly considered to be a Western country, although it has strong ties with a lot of Western countries due to its democratic leanings. Is there a particular reason for that?

One likely reason is that Israelis judge Chine from a different viewpoint than Europeans and Americans. More specifically - many Israelis have traveled a lot, which is not surprising, given that their country is very small (unlike the US) and that the neighboring countries are not largely inaccessible (unlike in Europe.) Besides vacations, there is also tradition of traveling after ending the military service - group trips often extending for many weeks or months, and involving a lot of hiking and similar activities. The preferred destinations are "exotic" and not very expensive countries, notably South America, India, and China. There is obviously much to see and admire in China, and interactions with locals are definitely fulfilling (to the extent that a language barrier can be overcome.)

Compare this with the views of Americans and Europeans, for whom China is mainly a subject in the news, an economic competitor, and a place known for its lack of democracy (or the bliss of the communism - depending on which end of the political spectrum you are.)

Answer (score 1):

> **Question:**
>
> Why does a plurality of Israelis hold a favorable view on China?

China as one of the world's largest economies is an important and lucrative trade partner for any nation.  It has long been so to Israel.  Israel has a significant amount of expertise and access to technology for a country as small as they are.  China has deep financial pockets and a need for that technology.  That's the answer to the question.

It is also true this trade relationship has sometimes caused significant angst for the United States who's technology sometimes has been foundational to these exports.

Quick Demonstration of Israeli transfers of Military Technology to China.

- 2000 - **[Israel and US clash over spy plane sale to China](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2000/apr/10/israel)**
- 2005 - **[US acts over Israeli arms sales to China](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2005/jun/13/usa.israel)**
- 2013 - **[Israel Passes U.S. Military Technology to China](https://www.military.com/defensetech/2013/12/24/report-israel-passes-u-s-military-technology-to-china)**

China's J-10 fighter aircraft has been described by Chinese media as **[the backbone of the Chinese Airforce](https://www.businessinsider.com/china-fighter-jet-fleet-growing-size-capability-pentagon-2023-10)**.  In the West, the Chinese J-10 in the late 1990's advanced the Chinese air force from 1950's technology by three decades.  This aircraft is based on an Israeli "home grown" fighter plane named the Lavi.

- **[Why China Looked To Israel's Lavi Jet For Its J-10 'Vigorous Dragon'](https://nationalinterest.org/blog/reboot/why-china-looked-israels-lavi-jet-its-j-10-vigorous-dragon-160931)**
- **[Pakistan Purchases Chinese Jets Based on Scrapped Israeli Lavi Fighter](https://www.haaretz.com/world-news/asia-and-australia/2022-01-05/ty-article/pakistan-purchases-chinese-jets-based-on-scrapped-israeli-lavi-fighter/0000017f-f71b-d887-a7ff-ffffa08e0000)**
- 2023 - **[Israeli tech-transfer to China turns the J-10 into a ‘Chinese’ F-16](https://bulgarianmilitary.com/2023/09/12/israeli-tech-transfer-to-china-turns-the-j-10-into-a-chinese-f-16/)**

The Israeli Lavi fighter's development was to a significant degree paid for by U.S. taxpayers.

- 1986 - **[How U.S. Came to Underwrite Israel's Lavi Fighter Project](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1986/08/06/how-us-came-to-underwrite-israels-lavi-fighter-project)**

> United States pays $550 million to research Israeli home grown fighter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the Chinese helping the Jews during WW2 is also part of the reason.

> One of the most extraordinary stories in Shanghai's history took place the neighbourhood of Tilanqiao, which served as "a modern-day Noah's Ark" for Jews during WW2.

> Despite Shanghai being more than 7,000km from their homes in Germany, Poland and Austria, more than 20,000 stateless Jews fled to China's largest city to escape the Holocaust between 1933 and 1941. Shanghai was not just a safe haven. It was also a modern city with an established community of Russian Jews, who a decade earlier, had built the structure that held that Star of David: the Ohel Moshe Synagogue.

> Shanghai would go on to harbor nearly 20,000 Jewish evacuees from Europe before and during World War II. But life there was not always pretty. Japan had invaded China earlier in the decade and eventually seized control of the entire city. The Japanese army forced Jewish refugees into one working-class district, Hongkou, leading to crowded, unsanitary conditions in which disease spread rapidly.

Refer to:

1. [How China saved more than 20000 Jews during WW2](https://www.bbc.com/travel/article/20210405-how-china-saved-more-than-20000-jews-during-ww2)
2. [Where did 20000 Jews hide from the Holocaust? In Shanghai](https://www.npr.org/2023/08/06/1192118339/jewish-refugees-shanghai-world-war-ii)

Answer (score -1):

Pro:

- You can buy cheap things from them
- They don't complain about the next genocide in line
- Nothing holocaust happened there

Contra:

- Competitors of the Big Brother USA